# SQL Query and Array with IN function

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have an array that I need to match with another dimension (VARCHAR). I need a User_ID to match against a list of the below Test_IDs, however the Test ID will always vary so I can't hard code in the variables.

Example array with the dimension

```
TestID[14782273,10904275,1454477270,16526331,1323009,1450722,529479190,1195598]
```

---

```
SUM(CASE
    WHEN User_ID IN TEST_ID
           THEN 1
        ELSE
        0
      END)
      AS Complete_Items
```

Comment: SQL doesn't have arrays. What is the datatype of `TestID`?

Comment: @Barmar Presto (which Athena is based on) has arrays. See https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of array functions are [here](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html), and the `array_position()` function is useful here.

```
SUM(CASE
    WHEN array_position(TEST_ID, User_ID) > 0 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END) AS Complete_Items
```